# Error al compilar en C++: XXX undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: c++

[image: Ese es el error que me sale al compilar y ejecutar el código]

Los mensajes son:

> `línea 51: 'malloc' undeclared (first use in this function)`.
>   `...`
>   `línea 99: 'free' undeclared (first use in this function)`.
>   `...`
>   `línea 111: 'free' undeclared (first use in this function)`.

Este es mi código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ASCENDENTE 1
#define DESCENDENTE 0

typedef struct _nodo {
   int valor;
   struct _nodo *siguiente;
   struct _nodo *anterior;
} tipoNodo;

typedef tipoNodo *pNodo;
typedef tipoNodo *Lista;

/* Funciones con listas: */
void Insertar(Lista *l, int v);
void Borrar(Lista *l, int v);

void BorrarLista(Lista *);
void MostrarLista(Lista l, int orden);

int main() {
   Lista lista = NULL;
   pNodo p;

   Insertar(&lista, 20);
   Insertar(&lista, 10);
   Insertar(&lista, 40);
   Insertar(&lista, 30);

   MostrarLista(lista, ASCENDENTE);
   MostrarLista(lista, DESCENDENTE);

   Borrar(&lista, 10);
   Borrar(&lista, 15);
   Borrar(&lista, 45);
   Borrar(&lista, 30);

   MostrarLista(lista, ASCENDENTE);
   MostrarLista(lista, DESCENDENTE);

   BorrarLista(&lista);

   return 0;
}

void Insertar(Lista *lista, int v) {
   pNodo nuevo, actual;

   /* Crear un nodo nuevo */
   nuevo = (pNodo)malloc(sizeof(tipoNodo));
   nuevo->valor = v;

   /* Colocamos actual en la primera posición de la lista */
   actual = *lista;
   if(actual) while(actual->anterior) actual = actual->anterior;
   /* Si la lista está vacía o el primer miembro es mayor que el nuevo */
   if(!actual || actual->valor > v) {
      /* Añadimos la lista a continuación del nuevo nodo */
      nuevo->siguiente = actual; 
      nuevo->anterior = NULL;
      if(actual) actual->anterior = nuevo;
      if(!*lista) *lista = nuevo;
   }
   else {
      /* Avanzamos hasta el último elemento o hasta que el siguiente tenga 
         un valor mayor que v */
      while(actual->siguiente &&actual->siguiente->valor <= v) 
         actual = actual->siguiente;
      /* Insertamos el nuevo nodo después del nodo anterior */
      nuevo->siguiente = actual->siguiente;
      actual->siguiente = nuevo;
      nuevo->anterior = actual;
      if(nuevo->siguiente) nuevo->siguiente->anterior = nuevo;
   }
}

void Borrar(Lista *lista, int v) {
   pNodo nodo;

   /* Buscar el nodo de valor v */
   nodo = *lista;
   while(nodo && nodo->valor < v) nodo = nodo->siguiente;
   while(nodo && nodo->valor > v) nodo = nodo->anterior;

   /* El valor v no está en la lista */
   if(!nodo || nodo->valor != v) return;

   /* Borrar el nodo */
   /* Si lista apunta al nodo que queremos borrar, apuntar a otro */
   if(nodo == *lista)
     if(nodo->anterior) *lista = nodo->anterior;
     else *lista = nodo->siguiente;

   if(nodo->anterior) /* no es el primer elemento */
      nodo->anterior->siguiente = nodo->siguiente;
   if(nodo->siguiente) /* no es el último nodo */
      nodo->siguiente->anterior = nodo->anterior;
   free(nodo);
}

void BorrarLista(Lista *lista) {
   pNodo nodo, actual;

   actual = *lista;
   while(actual->anterior) actual = actual->anterior;

   while(actual) {
      nodo = actual;
      actual = actual->siguiente;
      free(nodo);
   }
   *lista = NULL;
}

void MostrarLista(Lista lista, int orden) {
   pNodo nodo = lista;

   if(!lista) printf("Lista vacía");

   nodo = lista;
   if(orden == ASCENDENTE) {
      while(nodo->anterior) nodo = nodo->anterior;
      printf("Orden ascendente: ");
      while(nodo) {
         printf("%d -> ", nodo->valor);
         nodo = nodo->siguiente;
      }
   }
   else {
      while(nodo->siguiente) nodo = nodo->siguiente;
      printf("Orden descendente: ");
      while(nodo) {
         printf("%d -> ", nodo->valor);
         nodo = nodo->anterior;
      }
   }

   printf("\n");
}
```

El error está en la línea `nuevo = (pNodo)malloc(sizeof(tipoNodo));`
También en `free(nodo);` 
Espero me puedan ayudar (agrego imagen del error que me sale al compilar y ejecutar el código).

Comment: Sería de gran ayuda si indicaras el error **exacto** que obtienes: ¿ al compilarlo ? ¿ al ejecutarlo ? Y, en ese último caso, ¿ que esperas ? ¿ que obtienes ?

Comment: Ya lo edité con los errores que salen al compilarlo y ejecutarlo

Comment: Ummm... Llevo un rato mirando el código, y **no veo** esas líneas por ningún lado. O_o. Dejo urgentemente el sitio para acercarme al oculista.

Comment: Disculpe, me equivoqué al copiar el código, ahora sí, está corregido

Comment: Yo no se c++ pero `typedef tipoNodo *pNodo;
typedef tipoNodo *Lista;` no me parece correcto, y aunque agregaste la linea que da error no mencionas el **tipo de error** que esta dando.

Comment: Acaba de adjuntar la imagen del error que me da al compilar y ejecutar el código

Comment: Siguiendo [¿Cuánto énfasis se debe hacer en editar el título de las preguntas, a fin de enriquecer el sitio?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1656/19610), he cambiado el título por algo más *descriptivo* y *acorde* al tema real.

Comment: Disculpe, soy nuevo en esta página y pues no estoy muy familiarizado con eso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los mensajes de error te lo dicen muy claro:

> `malloc( ) undeclared`
>   `free( ) undeclared`

El compilador **no encuentra** la declaración de dichas funciones; te falta incluir el archivo de cabecera necesario; en tu caso, `<cstdlib>` (o `stdlib.h`).

```
#include <cstdlib>
```

Con eso debería de bastar.

Comment: No me importa el -1, pero agradecería un *mensaje* indicando el *porqué*.

Comment: No tengo idea de quién le habrá dado el -1
Con respecto a su respuesta, me sirvió mucho, gracias. Una última pregunta si no es mucha molestia: Ya no me sale ningún mensaje de error, pero aún me sale esto _[Warning] no newline at end of file_
A qué se puede deber?

Comment: Pon una línea en blanco **al final** del archivo.

Comment: Ya no tengo ese error, pero a la hora de compilar y ejecutar el código, sale la pantalla y se cierra rápido, qué puedo hacer ?

Comment: Disculpe una vez más por las molestias, acabo de solucionar el problema añadiendo la libreria `#include <conio.h>` y añadiendo al final `getch() ;`

Comment: @T.Damian conio.h no es parte del estándar C. Si quieres poner una pausa en tu programa, sería mejor usar `getchar()` que sí es estándar y portable

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro muchas gracias por la sugerencia, ya lo modifiqué

Answer (score -1):

//elaborar un programa que calcule el area de untriangulo conociendo sus lados.la formula es:
           //area= (p(p-a)(p-b)(p-c))^1/2  DONDE P ES EL PÉRIOMETRO

> ```
> #include<iostream>
> #include<math.h>
> int main()
> {
>     double a, b, c, p, area;
>     cout << "ingresar datos: ";
>     cin << a << b << c;
>     p=(a+b+c)/2;
>     area = sqrt(p*(p-a)*(p-b)*(p-c));
>     cout<<"el area es:"<<area<<endl;
> }
> ```

mesale estos errores

> In function `int main()':`cout' undeclared (first use this
>   function)    (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once for
>   each function it appears in.)   `cin' undeclared (first use this
>   function)`endl' undeclared (first use this function)

Comment: Hola, por favor mejora la calidad de la respuesta.